# How do I report on a session variable in google analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am new to custom variables in google analytics.  I don't understand how to grab session/post variables from a user.

I am trying to capture `$_SESSION['usercountry']` and add it to the GA data.  It simply displays the country from which a user is signed up.

From the GA

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
      2,                   // This custom var is set to slot #2.  Required parameter.
      'Country', // The name of the custom variable.  Required parameter.
      '???',               // The value of the custom variable.  Required parameter.
                           //  (you might set this value by default to No)
      2                    // Sets the scope to session-level.  Optional parameter.
]);
```

Do I just put in usercountry in where I have the question marks?

Answer (score 1):

Client-side JavaScript doesn't have access to `$_SESSION`, as the collection is kept server-side.

You'll need to *expose* the value to JavaScript somehow. One option is to simply include it in the initial output from PHP:

```
<script>
    var userCountry = <? echo json_encode($_SESSION['usercountry']) $>;
</script>
```

This uses [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) and takes advantage of [JSON](http://json.org/)'s relation and shared syntax with JavaScript, so it'll be parsed as a [JavaScript literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals). Presumably a `String`, so the result from the PHP `echo` would be similar to:

```
<script>
    var userCountry = "Country Name";
</script>
```

Then, you can use it for Google Analytics:

```
_gaq.push([
    '_setCustomVar',
    2,                 // This custom var is set to slot #2.  Required parameter.
    'Country',         // The name of the custom variable.  Required parameter.
    userCountry ,      // The value of the custom variable.  Required parameter.
                       //  (you might set this value by default to No)
    2                  // Sets the scope to session-level.  Optional parameter.
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I looked at about 20 tutorials and didn't get how these values were being passed because GA would have no idea what usercountry is.  Will test it out and look for results.

Comment: It is a string.  Why is "var userCountry = "Country Name"; needed?

Comment: @DavidMoore The `"Country Name"` is just an example of the output from PHP in the previous snippet; what JavaScript might parse. You don't need to include it.